# Ksp of Manganese Phosphate

Tags: solubility, equilibrium

I can't find the $K_{sp}$ value for Manganese Phosphate ($\ce{Mn_3(PO_4)_2}$) anywhere online. Has it been measured? What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the [MSDS entry](http://fs1.agrian.com/pdfs/Tech-Flo_Mn-15_0-7-0_%2882295%29_MSDS.pdf) tells me that the solubility is 50%. Converting, we get 0.5 g per gram of water, or 0.0005 g per liter of water. This is $s=1.4\times 10^{-6}$ moles per liter of water.

$K_{sp}=(3s)^3\times(2s)^2=6.14\times 10^{-27} \rm M^5 $

Comment: We should get 0.5 g of manganese phosphate per gram of solution (the remaining 0.5 gram is water). Per liter, approximately 500 gram (.5 * 1000) is manganese phosphate and not 0.0005 g (.5 / 1000) - there are 1000 g of water in 1 L of water.